# OC4J 10.1.3.5 / Spring3 Issue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oc4j

I'm using OC4J 10.1.3.5.0, and have an issue with the XML namespaces in the Spring XML files supplied in the WAR/EAR.

According to the Oracle documentation, there is a known issue in parsing the Spring 3 XSD files within OC4J, as this embeds the Oracle XMLParserV2 jar and uses this for all XML parsing (which has issues with some XSD tricks used in Spring 3 apparently).

I've folowed the Oracle work-around, defining my own XML parser shared libraries on the OC4J instance, and (in the orion-application.xml), defining the shared library to use. I created a shared library,'apache.xml', with xercesImpl (v 2.9.1), xml-apis (v 1.3.04), and xml-resolver (v 1.2). I tried defining the EAR to use the new library

```
<imported-shared-libraries>
    <imported-shared-library name="apache.xml"/>
</imported-shared-libraries>
```

I receive the following error

```
14:50:31 ERROR (UserId:) [DispatcherServlet] Context initialization failed 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: 
        Line 10 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webflow-config.xml] is invalid;
    nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: 
    The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'webflow:flow-executor'.
```

The webflow-config.xml file is defined as normal:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config 
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd">

    <!-- Executes web flows -->
    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry" />

    <!-- Rest of the file ... -->

</beans>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

[Edit]
The snippet:

```
<imported-shared-libraries>
    <imported-shared-library name="apache.xml"/>
</imported-shared-libraries>
```

should, of course read:

```
<imported-shared-libraries>
    <import-shared-library name="apache.xml"/>
</imported-shared-libraries>
```

Sorry!

Comment: Do you have spring-webflow jar added to the classpath of the project?

Comment: Yes. I have most of the Spring JAR files at this stage on the classpath of the WAR. So, the JARs get embedded in the WAR, which itself gets embedded in the EAR. (Sorry for the delay answering, I was not well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this. Turns out this was specifically because I was running OC4J on a Java 6 JVM. If anyone else gets this problem, here's what we did to resolve:

The Oracle XML parser does not handle the Spring 3 XSD files well, this is a know issue. You need to remove the Oracle XSD libraries for your application. In your `orion-application.xml` file, you need

```
<imported-shared-libraries>
    <remove-inherited name="oracle.xml"/>
</imported-shared-libraries>
```

The Oracle documentation then tells you to import a *new* shared library. However, if you're running OC4J on a Java 6 JVM (which we are!), you can't do this. It looks like there is an XML parser in the Java 6 core now, and importing Xerces libraries will conflict with these classes, causing weird errors.

Anyway, on Java 6, remove the Oracle libraries, but don't import any other ones!